# Multiple CMake targets in Teamcity

Tags: cmake, teamcity

I can specify multiple CMake targets in one build. For example:

```
cmake --build ./build/ --target t1 t2 t3
```

However, setting those targets in the "Build target:" field in the Teamcity Build Step configuration produces this command line:

```
cmake --build ./build/ --target 't1 t2 t3'
```

This causes build to fail.

Is there a way to specify multiple targets in one step? Or the philosophy is to have one target per step?

Teamcity version 2022.04.4 (build 108763)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using TeamCity CMake plugin. I'm afraid in that case you can't alter plugin behaviour unless you're willing to patch plugin (https://github.com/JetBrains/CMake-runner-plugin). Consider switching to command line runner and manually generate cmake cmd